# Html game inventory grid

Tags: html, css

Trying to make an outside div to house the grid for an inventory. In the following jsfiddle this works, but I then need to move this outside div to an absolute position on the screen. If you uncomment the position: absolute in the css on the outside grid the divs inside all stack on each other.

https://jsfiddle.net/myr3u2mo/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>

    <style>
        div {
            width: 300px;
            height: 600px;
            background-color: orange;
            left: 100px;
            //position: absolute;
        }

        div div {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            outline: 1px solid;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I move that outside grid around anywhere I want while maintaining the inside grid?

Comment: Your style rules are colliding because it's all div.  Try using a class for your grids so you can give them a clear set of separate style rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the inner divs are getting the `position: absolute;` style too. Try adding a class to your outer div and using that as the selector for positioning.

```
<div class="inventory">
    <div></div>
    ...
</div>

.inventory {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: That did it. Interestingly the lines of the inside grids became darker/thicker/bolder. Why would that be?

Comment: Because those are two borders of two adjacent divs

Comment: And before the positioning being absolute they weren't? I would think it would have been like that either way.

Comment: My apology, they looked like borders but they are outlines, which don't stack. let me check :)

Comment: Before, you had the `background: orange;` style overflowing onto the child divs too. The background overlays the outline. If you switch to `border`, it should remain consistent.

Comment: Using `border` didn't seem to work for me.  You could always go with a `box-shadow`, though, if it doesn't work for you.  Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/ymve6m3r/

Comment: @Anthony Yeah, using border will add 2px onto the width/height of each inner div, which will overflow the outer div. If you add `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` it should be fine though.

Comment: @Will Still not working for me in Chrome 43.  The problem is that the inner borders are 2px wide, not that the divs are overflowing the outer div.

Comment: @Anthony Ah I see, yeah uniform borders in a grid can be tricky. Here is a [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/myr3u2mo/1/).